# What does list.index() with multiple arguments do in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I can't say for certain that this is the fastest way:

```
i = -1
for j in xrange(n):
    i = x.index(True, i + 1)
```

`x` : list of Booleans here

`n` : number of occurrences

`True` : element searched

In the above code, what does `i = x.index(True, i + 1)` do exactly?

Precisely, what is the role of the second parameter `i + 1`?

I couldn't find any example with multiple parameters on `list.index()`.

**Edit:** I'm working with Python 2.7

Comment: index(...) method of builtins.list instance
    L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

Comment: Python's documentation is very good.  If you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), you'll find that the `i + 1` is the starting place to search for the element.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about something that is inherently easier to find, and more likely to stay accurate, in Python's official documentation.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, so I didn't look in the Python 3.x doc. My bad.

Comment: This information is also available in the Python 2 docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types FWIW, here are the relevant Python _2.1_ docs https://docs.python.org/release/2.1/lib/typesseq-mutable.html And of course there's always `help(list.index)`, although I guess that is a little terse if you don't already know what `start` and `stop` are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list.index(x[, start[, end]])
```

Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

The optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in the slice notation and are used to limit the search to a particular subsequence of the list. The returned index is computed relative to the beginning of the full sequence rather than the start argument.

Visit [this documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more info

```
fruits = ['orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'apple', 'banana']

fruits.index('banana')
```

> > > 3

```
fruits.index('banana', 4)  # Find next banana starting a position 4
```

> > > 6

Answer (score 4):

As can be found in [the documentation for Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html), the second parameter is used to indicate a starting index.

The example used in the documentation shows the difference between using the second parameter and omitting it:

```
>>> fruits.index('banana')
3
>>> fruits.index('banana', 4)  # Find next banana starting a position 4
6
```

A third parameter is also available, indicating an end index.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter limits the search to items **at or after that position** in the given list. There is also a 3rd parameter to avoid searching the list until it's end.

```
s.index(x[, i[, j]])

index of the first occurrence of x in s (at or after index i and before index j)
```

From: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations